# Error while creating new project in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to create new angular project using the command `ng new my-app`. And the installed versions are listed below

- Angular CLI : 6.0
- Node version : 10.5.0
- Npm : 6.1.0

I am getting the following error message,

```
ERR! path D:\ng\newapp\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4c0ca0e6\lib\lib.dom.d.ts
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\ng\newapp\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4c0ca0e6\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\ng\newapp\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4c0ca0e6\lib\lib.dom.d.ts']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\ng\newapp\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4c0ca0e6\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'D:\\ng\\newapp\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4c0ca0e6\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'D:\\ng\\newapp\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4c0ca0e6\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'D:\\ng\\newapp\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4c0ca0e6\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts',
npm ERR!   parent: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: What Operating System are you using? It seems Window to me. Is It?

Comment: My machine operates on windows 10

Comment: Are you running command prompt as administrator?

Comment: Yes i am running command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

**temporary fix, downgrade npm to 5.3**

```
npm install npm@5.3 -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Use administrator privileges. Error says you are not using admin CMD

Answer (score 0):

- Install packages after closing your code editor,

Answer (score -3):

Are you using Node Cmd or any IDE(like VSCode) to create new project

try this command

1. npm i -g @angular/cli
2. ng new app-name
3. cd app-name.
4. ng serve

Comment: If you have addl. questions about issue, post it as comment.  Do not post answers that does not answer OP's question

Comment: I tested same command, it doesn't work. check if our are using http npm registry instead of https, you have to choose https . or check if there is a firewall